# How can I format a nested array to make it so I can write it to a file in one line?

Tags: php

I have a nested array and need to format it so it can be written to a single line in a log file.

The entry looks something like this:

```
$object = [
    'date_time' = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'user' => 'Mike'
    'actions' => [
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'foo2' => 'bar2'
    ]
];
```

I'd like to get it to look like this:

2024-03-11 00:00:000,Mike,bar,bar2

I tried to use the `implode(`) function, but it doesn't seem to work with nested arrays.

```
Warning: Array to string conversion
```

Comment: What else did you try? Keep in mind that unserializing the array in the original way might be difficult when ignoring nested elements. Why not use json_encode or serialize?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by iterating over each element in the array using a foreach and checks if the current value is an array, then merge the values of that array in the `$values`. If the current value is not an array, it simply appends it to the `$values` array.

```
<?php

$object = [
    'date_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'user' => 'Mike',
    'actions' => [
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'foo2' => 'bar2'
    ]
];

$values = [];

foreach ($object as $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $values = array_merge($values, array_values($value));
    } else {
        $values[] = $value;
    }
}

echo implode(",", $values);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/3Ji57

Answer (score 0):

```php
$object = [
    'date_time' = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'user' => 'Mike'
    'actions' => [
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'foo2' => 'bar2'
    ]
];

$row = '';
array_walk_recursive($object, function ($v) use (&$row) { $row .= ($row ? ',' : '') . $v; });
echo $row;
```